# Schema for an object with swagger

Tags: node.js, object, schema, yaml, swagger

I am writing a schema for two get routes where the result is an object like

```
{
  "id":"49077acb6ac8",
  "info":
    {
      "name":"test"
    }
}
```

Actually I got this :

```
/*
* @swagger
*  definitions:
*    getVCenter:
*      id:
*        type: string
*        format: uuid
*      info:
*        type: object
*      properties:
*        name:
*          type: string
*        fullName:
*          type: string
*        vendor:
*          type: string
* /v1/vcenters/:
*   get:
*     tags:
*       - vcenters
*     summary: Get availables vCenters.
*     description: Get a list of availables vCenters.
*     produces:
*       - application/json
*     responses:
*       200:
*         description: an array of vCenters
*         schema:
*           $ref : '#definitions/getVCenter'
*/
```

But it doesn't work anymore.

Can someone explain to me what I did wrong please?

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: I mean it is not display the doc

Answer (score 0):

There are syntax errors in your annotation.

The indentation of `info` properties should be as follows:

```
*      info:
*        type: object
*        properties:  # <-- "properties" must be on the same level as "type: object"
*          name:
*            type: string
*          fullName:
*            type: string
*          vendor:
*            type: string
```

In `$ref`s, there must be a `/` after `#` - replace `#definitions` with `#/definitions`:

```
$ref : '#/definitions/getVCenter'
```

Also, if the response is supposed to be "an array of vCenters" and not a single vCenter, then the response schema should be:

```
*     responses:
*       200:
*         description: an array of vCenters
*         schema:
*           type: array
*           items:
*             $ref : '#/definitions/getVCenter'
```

Comment: and where about the id before the info ?

Comment: `id` definition is fine, but you may want to remove `format: uuid` because it's for [UUIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Format) and `"49077acb6ac8"` is not a UUID.

Comment: It was for stackoverflow exemple but it is an uuid in my case